# How to save a non-fuzzy image of a control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, render, blurry, rendertargetbitmap

I am using a DrawingContext to draw images.  I then render the result to a RenderTargetBitmap.  I also render a Canvas to the same RenderTargetBitmap.  Even though the pixel boundaries are crisp on screen, they become blurred and fuzzy when saved.

In the screenshot below, you can see the issue (with BitmapScalingMode = NearestNeighbor). [image]

Here it is with BitmapScalingMode = HighQuality.  It's smoother but not crisp and clean.
[image]

Here is the relevant section of my code.  You can see that I tried setting the RenderOptions at multiple places but it seems to have no effect.

```
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(drawingVisual, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);   // This forces the scaling to be on even-pixel boundaries
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(drawCanvas, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);  // This forces the scaling to be on even-pixel boundaries
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(result, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);  // This forces the scaling to be on even-pixel boundaries

        using (DrawingContext context = drawingVisual.RenderOpen()) {
            context.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(size.Width, size.Height)));

            if (layers.Count >= 1 && layers[0].LayerImage != null && layers[0].LayerImage.Source != null && gridImage.Children[1].Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                context.DrawImage(layers[0].LayerImage.Source, new Rect(size)); // Draw first image.

            context.Close();
        }

        result.Render(drawingVisual);

        drawCanvas.Measure(drawCanvas.RenderSize);
        drawCanvas.Arrange(new Rect(drawCanvas.RenderSize));

        for (int i = 0; i < drawCanvas.Children.Count; i++) {
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(drawCanvas.Children[i], BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);  // This forces the scaling to be on even-pixel boundaries
        }

        result.Render(drawCanvas);

        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        if (result!= null) {
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)result));
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
```

Comment: Try changing your `BitmapScalingMode` to `HighQuality`

Comment: The last time I had thought I had that problem, it really was an IfranView display option.

Comment: @lll: I tried HighQuality but it didn't really help.  See the screenshot in the edit above.

Comment: @TAW: I've tried it in many programs including my own and they all look the same, so I think it's my save code rather than the viewer.

Comment: OK. Just a thought.  The images look anti-aliased. I notice that you use PixelFormats.Pbgra32; have you tried PixelFormats.Bgra32?

Comment: The hard-coded output DPI of 96 might be an issue.  WPF does not always use the same DPI; it'll depend on your screen settings.  A DPI mismatch would cause blurring.

Comment: Using this format `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` saved crisp images for me.

Comment: @RogerN: What DPI would I use instead?

Comment: @TAW: RenderTargetBitmap doesn't support the formats you suggested.  I get runtime and compile time errors (respectively) on your two format suggestions.

Comment: @TaW you cannot mix System.Drawing and WPF

Comment: @springy76 I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @nb1forxp have you fixed that yet?

Comment: What value have `size` variable and `drawCanvas.RenderSize` when you call 'result.Render(drawingVisual);'?

Comment: If anyone runs to similar issue RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(canvas, EdgeMode.Aliased) might help you before calling the Render-method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have fixed that but that function works very good on my side.

```
    public BitmapSource SnapShotPNG(UIElement source)
    {
        double actualWidth = source.RenderSize.Width;
        double actualHeight = source.RenderSize.Height;

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)actualWidth, (int)actualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);


        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(source);
            context.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(actualWidth, actualHeight)));
        }
        source.Measure(source.RenderSize); //Important
        source.Arrange(new Rect(source.RenderSize)); //Important

        renderTarget.Render(visual);

        try
        {
            return new CroppedBitmap(renderTarget, new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)actualWidth, (int)actualHeight));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try.

Comment: not yet, sorry!  my code has been reformatted since I put up the post, so I need to deconvolute it to figure out how to test your function.  Stay tuned!

Comment: I've been using something similar for a while, but had to actually run measure + arrange with 1 pixel bigger for width and height, and then run it again at the correct size. If you see any weirdness with things not rendering then try that [sic]

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static BitmapSource CaptureScreen(this UIElement visualElement, int? desiredLongestEdge = null)
    {
        double scale = 1;
        if (desiredLongestEdge.HasValue)
        {
            if (visualElement.RenderSize.Width > visualElement.RenderSize.Height)
            {
                scale = desiredLongestEdge.Value/ visualElement.RenderSize.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                scale = desiredLongestEdge.Value / visualElement.RenderSize.Height ;
            }
        }

        var targetBitmap =
                     new RenderTargetBitmap(
                        (int) Math.Ceiling(scale * (visualElement.RenderSize.Width + 1)),
                         (int) Math.Ceiling(scale * (visualElement.RenderSize.Height + 1)),
                                                       scale * 96,
                                                       scale * 96,
                                                        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        visualElement.Measure(visualElement.RenderSize); //Important
        visualElement.Arrange(new Rect(visualElement.RenderSize)); //Important

        targetBitmap.Render(visualElement);

        return targetBitmap;
    }
```